# Does each code of an ADC have a DNL value?

Tags: adc

DNL error is defined as the difference between an actual step width and the ideal value of 1LSB 
DNL is specified after the static gain error has been removed. It is defined as follows:

DNL = |[(VD+1- VD)/VLSB-IDEAL - 1] | , where 0 < D < 2N - 2.

Further information at this [link](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/283).

So, it means that for each step, there is a different DNL character?

Comment: DNL and INL are the characteristics of all the practical ADCs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a DNL value for each code of an ADC, except of the code at each end of the ADC range.  ADC data sheets contain specifications for the DNL.  The DNL specification refers to the maximum and minimum values of the DNL; that is, the most positive and most negative DNL found at *any* code in the ADC range.

Many ADC data sheets also contain plots of the typical DNL across the ADC range, as shown here for a 12 bit converter (4096 codes, 4094 DNL values).

[image: DNL Plot]

Answer (score 0):

> For each step, there is a different DNL characteristic?

Yes.
The actual DNL varies from one step to the next.
The datasheet for many ADCs graphs the actual DNL at each code (at each step).
For example, Figure 2-7 of the [MCP3301 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21700E.pdf).

Often people say things like "The DNL of this ADC is ...",
as if it had a single DNL.
They are referring to the worst-case DNL.
The worst-case DNL is the maximum of the absolute values of each actual DNL, one at each step (under some given conditions).

Occasionally -- such as Figure 2-6 and 2-8 of the MCP3301 data sheet --
people talk about "the" positive DNL (meaning the worst-case maximum positive DNL)
and "the" negative DNL (meaning the worst-case most negative DNL) under the given conditions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_nonlinearity

[Texas Instruments: "Understanding Data Converters"](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa013/slaa013.pdf)

> Do some ADC have a single DNL letter?

Microchip often prints a label on top of its ADCs -- for example, the MCP3301-B, MCP3201-B, MCP3301-C, MCP3201-C -- with a single letter indicating whether it passed the most stringent nonlinearity tests, or whether it failed those tests but passed slightly more relaxed nonlinearity tests.

- The -B chips have +- 1 LSB maximum INL.
- The -C chips have +- 2 LSB maximum INL.

Other data-converter manufacturers have similar labeling schemes.